# How can I export a list of my RSS feeds from Google Reader?

Tags: google-reader, export

How can I export a list of my RSS feeds from Google Reader?

I can copy the 'Subscriptions' page, but it's not a very good format for exporting out into other applications.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Import/Export -> [Export your subscriptions as an OPML file](https://www.google.com/reader/subscriptions/export?hl=en).

A little [info about OPML files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPML).

Answer (score 3):

Settings -> Import/Export

The only export option is as an [OPML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPML) file.  This file *should* do the trick for your other RSS reader(s).